# How to access object and its method in another class

Tags: java, variables, object

For eg both `class` are in same `package`

```
class A extends JFrame{

    public JTextField username = new JTextField;
    A a = new A();
    ------------------------------
    ------------------------------
}

class B extends JFrame{
    String user;

    // i am able to acess like this
    user = new A().username.getText();
    //but i want to acess like followin and its not working
    user = a.username.getText();
}
```

Suggest me if u can

Answer (score 0):

Answer: There is nothing named `a` defined in `class B`. So `a.username` does not make any sense within `class B`.

Sorry for not saying more, but since it is not clear what you want to achieve, one cannot say more.

Comment: Note that `class B` does not inherit from `class A`. This might (or might not) be a mistake.

Additional comment:

If you are sure that there will be only one "a" for the whole program, you could make it a static member:

```
class A {
   static A a = new A ();
   ...
}

class B {
   void someMethod () {
      // you can access a in class A as follows:
      A.a.doSomething ();
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but class B does not inherit from class A. If there is nothing named a in B, then a does not make any sense in B.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class A extends JFrame{

    public JTextField username = new JTextField();        
}

class B extends JFrame{
    String user;
     A a=new A();   //Now A's instance a is B's field.

    //Now, Inside A Method You Can DO:
    user = a.username.getText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
class A extends JFrame{

  public static JTextField username = new JTextField;

} 

class B extends JFrame{
  String user;

  user = A.username.getText();
}
```